# Military anime with a main character who can power up others

Tags: story-identification, anime, military-sf

This anime character is from a military anime and he has a power from a contract with a shrine/deity that lets him power ups others. In one scene, he powers up an entire army and he did this with plugs and outlets to each person from the deity or shrine maiden.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the anime is Kyoukaisenjou no Horizon
and the character is Toori Aoi

Comment: While you are the original querent, can you elaborate on why this matches?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vw16HnPt3NU watch this and you should get it

Comment: :-D That's kind of my point. Your answer should stand up as an answer to the question. Embedding the link isn't a bad idea, but you should explain why it's relevant (especially since YouTube clips get taken down on a regular basis) and you should provide a description of the anime itself to provide context details.

Comment: Also, don't forget to accept by clicking on the checkmark by your answer.